# Curves in the intersection of a plane and a closed connected manifold.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose $M$ is a connected, closed $2$-dimensional manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and consider the set $I$, which is the intersection of $M$ with some plane $P$.

1. Can the $I$ always be described in terms of Jordan curves in any neat way? While generally the intersection will be describable as a disjoin union of Jordan curves, there are some degenerate cases where the intersection is composed of multiple Jordan curves that share an edge, so it might instead make sense to consider the set of minimal Jordan curves that lie in the intersection.
2. Is there any way to describe the number of Jordan curves and their containment relation (the partial ordering of one curve being contained in the interior of the other curve) that lie in the intersection of $I$?

---

Some examples:

If $M$ is convex, it's quite easy to see that the intersection with a plane is either empty, or a single loop, and similarly, I'd think (though I'm not sure how to show this) this is also true if $M$ has positive Gaussian curvature everywhere.

If $M$ is the torus, we can slice the torus "horizontally" so as to get two loops, one contained in the other. We can also slice "vertically" and get two loops that are non-intersecting. In addition to that, we can slice it so as to create a single loop, like the convex case above.

The genus of the torus doesn't seem relevant - the case of creating two loops with one in the other can be achieved if we slice a handless cup, and the case of creating two loops that do not intersect can be created if we slice a bean-like shape.

---

What about the general case? What are some tools or approaches that could be used to describe this problem? E.g. something that would at least formalize the examples I've given above. I'd appreciate reference that would cover this topic.

Comment: Your choice of tags strongly suggests that $M$ is smoothly embedded. Is it?

Comment: It's the standard Morse Theory stuff. Away from critical points, the level sets are submanifolds so will be a disjoint union of Jordan curves (possibly nested, e.g. push part of a sphere or torus back "into" itself, and then push part of that back out, etc.). At critical points your curves will have to join or split apart, which could be basically any type of curve singularity. You can always locally perturb things (since Morse functions are plentiful) so that at each critical point exactly two loops break apart or come together. A book on Morse Theory would be my recommendation.

Comment: For instance, the intersection can be homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, everything is supposed to be smooth. My intention was to really just consider "common" smooth surfaces, without boundary and self intersection. I'm not really sure how to specify that exactly, maybe something like... a bounded set having the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is also a smooth manifold without boundary.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you, I'll look into it.